# Table Search only first TD

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript search function that works very well. However, it only searches the first **td** in the table and no others.
It appears to be working only for the **tr**

Full Code:

PHP:

Create a table to display the output

```
    echo '<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">';
    echo '<div class="table-responsive">';
    echo '<table id="myTable"><tr bgcolor="#cccccc"><td>Name</td><td>Department</td><td>E-Mail Address</td><td>Office Phone</td><td>Mobile</td></tr>';
```

For each account returned by the search

```
    for ($x=0; $x<$entries['count']; $x++){
```

Retrieve values from Active Directory

First Name

```
        $LDAP_FirstName = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]['givenname'][0])) {
            $LDAP_FirstName = $entries[$x]['givenname'][0];
            if ($LDAP_FirstName == "NULL"){
                $LDAP_FirstName = "";
            }
        }
```

Last Name

```
        $LDAP_LastName = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]['sn'][0])) {
            $LDAP_LastName = $entries[$x]['sn'][0];
            if ($LDAP_LastName == "NULL"){
                $LDAP_LastName = "";
            }
        }
```

Department

```
        $LDAP_Department = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]['department'][0])) {
            $LDAP_Department = $entries[$x]['department'][0];
            if ($LDAP_Department == "NULL"){
                $LDAP_Department = "";
            }
        }
```

Email address

```
        $LDAP_InternetAddress = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]['mail'][0])) {
            $LDAP_InternetAddress = $entries[$x]['mail'][0];    
            if ($LDAP_InternetAddress == "NULL"){
                $LDAP_InternetAddress = "";
            }
        }
```

IPPhone

```
        $LDAP_OfficePhone = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]['ipphone'][0])) {
            $LDAP_OfficePhone = $entries[$x]['ipphone'][0];
            if ($LDAP_OfficePhone == "NULL"){
                $LDAP_OfficePhone = "";
            }
        }
```

Mobile Number

```
        $LDAP_CellPhone = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]['mobile'][0])) {
            $LDAP_CellPhone = $entries[$x]['mobile'][0];
            if ($LDAP_CellPhone == "NULL"){
                $LDAP_CellPhone = "";
            }
        }
```

Fill the table

```
        echo "<tr><td>".$LDAP_FirstName." " .$LDAP_LastName."</td><td>".$LDAP_Department."</td><td><a class='one' href='mailto:" .$LDAP_InternetAddress. "'>" .$LDAP_InternetAddress."</td><td>".$LDAP_OfficePhone."</td><td>".$LDAP_CellPhone."</td><tr>";


      } //END for loop
    } //END FALSE !== $result

ldap_unbind($ldap_connection); // Clean up after ourselves.
echo("</table>");
echo("</div>"); 
} //END ldap_bind
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
// Declare variables 
var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

// Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
  td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
     if (td) {
       if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         tr[i].style.display = "";
       } else {
         tr[i].style.display = "none";
       }
     } 
   }
 }
```

Updated with full code. Thanks

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Try this? `td = tr[i].querySelectorAll("td")[0];`

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your table looks like? Your current code will check the first TD in each TR. If you want to check all TD in all TR, you need to loop through TD the same way you looped TR

Comment: Updated with full code

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do it like this, I made a few small updates to the table structure (separating head from body) and used a class instead of an inline style for visibility changes.

[HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) has a few useful timesavers for getting into the dom object (`tBodies`, `rows`). Using that method to access the table you can then either use `Object.keys()` like I have here or a standard `for ...in` loop to iterate through and check your conditions.

I usually consider re-searching to be a reset so will make everything invisible by default and then only show matches, this also cleans up the code by removing the need for an else.

I appended numbers to the first td in the table to make demonstrating search easy, just pick a number.

```js
function myFunction() {
  let rows = document.getElementById('myTable').tBodies[0].rows;
  Object.keys(rows).forEach(key => {
    rows[key].classList.add('filter');
    const input = document.getElementById('myInput').value.toUpperCase();
    const current = rows[key].cells[0].innerText.toUpperCase()
    if (current.indexOf(input) > -1) {
      rows[key].classList.remove('filter');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.filter { display: none; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>E-Mail Address</th>
      <th>Office Phone</th>
      <th>Mobile</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>search1</td></td><td>Department</td><td>E-Mail Address</td><td>Office Phone</td><td>Mobile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>search2</td></td><td>Department</td><td>E-Mail Address</td><td>Office Phone</td><td>Mobile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>search3</td></td><td>Department</td><td>E-Mail Address</td><td>Office Phone</td><td>Mobile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>search4</td></td><td>Department</td><td>E-Mail Address</td><td>Office Phone</td><td>Mobile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>search5</td></td><td>Department</td><td>E-Mail Address</td><td>Office Phone</td><td>Mobile</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add for inner for. First 'for' for the next td and other 'for' for the next tr.